# Algorithm to calculate if bottleneck distance between Nodes s and t in a weighted undirected graph is at most W in O(V+E) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, graph-theory

I am currently working through exercise 9.b) on Page 270 of [Jeff Erickson's Algorithms book](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/Algorithms-JeffE.pdf)

> Consider a path between two vertices s and t in a undirected weighted
> graph G. The width of this path is the minimum weight of any edge in the
> path. The bottleneck distance between s and t is the width of the widest
> path from s to t. (If there are no paths from s to t, the bottleneck distance
> is −∞; on the other hand, the bottleneck distance from s to itself is ∞.)

> Describe an algorithm to solve the following problem in O(V + E) time:
> Given a undirected weighted graph G, two vertices s and t, and a
> weight W, is the bottleneck distance between s and t at most W?

I figured I can solve the problem in O(ElogE) time by modifying Kruskal's Algorithm to first find a maximum spanning tree and then use BFS to find the smallest weight on the path between s and t, however I don't really understand how this problem can be solved in O(E + V) time. I tried to modify the BFS algorithm in some way without any luck.

I was able to find a similar problem where it is asked to find if the bottleneck distance is at least W. This can easily be solved by deleting the edges with a weight less than W and using BFS to check if t is reachable from s. I don’t think this solution is directly adaptable, though.
Any tips?

Comment: Notice that you are not asked for FIND the path, only put an upper bound on its width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be rephrased as "is it impossible to connect s and t using edges with weight greater than W"

You already know how to run Kruskal's algorithm, so this is easy for you.  No need to sort the edges.  Just add all the edges with weight > W and see if s and t are connected.  Or DFS/BFS over the subgraph with those edges.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are not asked for FIND the path, only put an upper bound on its width.

If t is not reachable from s, the width is minus infinity - so it is less than W.  No work required.

You have to check for s == t, which will take no significant time.

The width of the path cannot be greater then the greatest weight of any edges.  Iterate over the edge, keeping track of the greatest weight.  Compare the greatest width to W and you are done.